# ASP.NET filtering dropdownlist basing on a previous one

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Let's say I have 2 tables:
a) TABLE A 
`|country| id_country |
|------- | ---------- |
|USA     | 1          |
|England | 2          |`

b) table B 
`city      | id_country
---------- | ----------
NY         |  1
LA         |  1
London     |  2
Manchester |  2`

Obviously if I chose USA the second dropdownlist should show NY and LA, but I don't know how to store a parametr of first dropdownlist. The code that filters second dropdownlist should probably look like this:

`select 
    B.city
from 
    A, B 
where 
    B.id_country = X`

And the x is parametr of firstdropdownlist (A.id_country), any ideas that would solve my problem?

Comment: Look for cascading dropdown list. There might be something already discussed. I can't tell from your question if you are asking this from a UI or DB perspective.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=asp.net%20cascading%20dropdownlist . Exact solution will depend on whether you're using Forms or MVC, and if you want to use ajax or not. Either way you need to handle the event where the user changes the value in the first dropdown, and cause that to submit a new query to the database, passing the selected value (which will become `x` in your example above). Then you return the result, and update the options available in the first dropdown. The question is not clear enough to give a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind first dropdown list with id_country as value member and country as display member. set `AutoPostBack` property of fist dropdown as true. add selected index change event to the first dropdown( double click dropdown on design view). on selected index changed event you can load the second dropdown.

```
select city, id_country from B where id_country = @id_country
```

set id_country parameter from first dropdown `SelectedValue`, set the second dropdown data source, display and value members and finally call `DataBind()` of second dropdown

check [Creating Cascading DropDownLists in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Creating-Cascading-DropDownLists-in-ASP.Net.aspx) if you need complete tutorial or you can try [AJAX Cascading DropDownList with data load using web service methods without full page poastback](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-Cascading-DropDown-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via some AJAX call, when you change what option is selected from the first dropdownlist you update the options in the second dropdownlist.

e.g:

You first load the first dropdown with countries.
But don't load any of the cities.

Then, when you choose some country from the dropdown, you update the options on the cities dropdown via some AJAX call for a service in your back-end based on the selected country.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, cities don't need to be loaded at first. I'm basing for now on a really easy example because I need 6 dropdownlists - every next is basing on a previous one and I think code behind this would be really problematic, so looking for some easier solution. Thanks, gonna check AJAX call out.

Comment: see this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/guschnwg/zL73rzqc/1/
you just need to make an ajax call and append to the select tag

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to store the parameter?  I have an application where we have categories of activities, and then two more levels of details, the 2nd level dependent on the category chosen, and the third depending on the second level.

Note - this app is written in Visual Basic, but I don't see anything about the concepts that would exclude c#.

In my example, the dropdown lists are called ddlActType (primary level), ddlAct2Type, and ddlAct3Type

The main list gets loaded when the page loads.  I create a variable called "selectAct" to store the value associated with the list choice, that matches the identity value on the table.  I actually don't need to create the variable, but the naming makes it more obvious what's going on for the purposes of maintenance.  When a choice is made, the secondary drop-down becomes available and is populated, using the chosen value as a filter for which items load in the secondary list.  Same for if a selection is made on the secondary, for that third level list.  In all of the "SelectedIndexChanged" routines, if they select the default/nothing, the subsequent lists are disabled and made invisible.

Primary list selection -

```
Protected Sub Activity_Type_Change(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles ddlActType.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim selectedAct As Integer = 0

    If ddlActType.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        ddlAct2Type.Visible = False
        lblSpecs.Visible = False
        ddlAct3Type.Visible = False
        lblDetails.Visible = False
    Else
        ddlAct2Type.Visible = True
        lblSpecs.Visible = True
        ddlAct3Type.Visible = False
        lblDetails.Visible = False
        selectedAct = ddlActType.SelectedValue
        Populate_Activity2_DDL(selectedAct)
    End If

End Sub
```

The routine that loads the second list, passing the first list selection as the filter parameter -

```
Protected Sub Populate_Activity2_DDL(ByVal selOne As Integer)

Dim strProcName As String = "usp_Get2ndLevelList"

Dim connSQL As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand

connSQL.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ThisDBsConnectionString").ToString



cmd = New SqlCommand(strProcName, connSQL)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ActTypeID", selOne)

cmd.Connection.Open()

   'dd_AT2_Values means drop-down list activity type 2 values'

Dim ddl_AT2_Values As SqlDataReader
ddl_AT2_Values = cmd.ExecuteReader()

If ddl_AT2_Values.HasRows = False Then
    ddlAct2Type.Visible = False
    lblSpecs.Visible = False
    cmd.Connection.Close()
    cmd.Connection.Dispose()

    Exit Sub
End If

ddlAct2Type.DataSource = ddl_AT2_Values
ddlAct2Type.DataValueField = "Ac2Type_ID"
ddlAct2Type.DataTextField = "Ac2T_Name"
ddlAct2Type.DataBind()

ddlAct2Type.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty))
ddlAct2Type.SelectedIndex = 0

cmd.Connection.Close()
cmd.Connection.Dispose()

        End If

End Sub
```

You really don't need to store the selection from the first list if you don't want to because it remains preserved as the selected value.  The original loading of that first list is done under non-postback conditions.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

If IsPostBack Then
Else
    Populate_Activity_DDL()
End If
End Sub
```

If you need more details, request them via comments and I'll edit and enhance as needed.